# How to target and change in CSS a class element from (react.js) Formik?

Tags: css, reactjs, formik

How would one target an element which is part of Formik and has the jsx-prefix?

HTML:

```
<p>
  {isMyProfile ? (
  <UserName />
              ) : (
   <PageHeading>
   {user?.firstname} {user?.lastname}
   </PageHeading>
              )}
</p>
```

CSS:

```
<button type="button" class="jsx-962024717 jsx-380790680 plain-button">
```

I got this CSS code from dev.tools, but I am not able to change the CSS of this element and target the UserName and PageHeading.

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` in your css?

Comment: ah, I see now that I havent given all the important information. Im adding the HTML in the code. 
Its part of Formik, so I have no idea how to target these HTML elements EditUserName and PageHeading